# Combining different user agent attributes in one CSS class

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I want to put an outline-color into a textbox when user types something wrong onto it. The problem is IE8 does not support the `outline` attribute (at least I test with no succeed) so I use `border` instead:

But I'd like to use `border` for IE8 and `outline` for browsers that support it.

```
.myclass
{
  border: ; // IE8 should use this
  outline: ; // Browser that support it must ignore the above one and get this.
}
```

I tested with IE8 and Chrome and both attributes are applied in Chrome and only the border in IE8.

Example:

```
.myclass
{
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline:#00FF00 dotted thick;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/puD97/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who said IE8 doesn't support `outline` property?

Still if you want different styles for IE and other browsers use IE specific stylesheets using IE specific cstylesheet comments

```
<!-- This will be ignored by all browsers but IE -->

<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Or target any specific IE versions

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Or in your page use this

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <style>
      /* Styles goes here */
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: No, I don't know different styles, I just though, and tried, that IE does not support outline. Can you please edit your answer and enter a x-browser outline class? Thank you.

Comment: @a_maar IE8 does support `outline` property

Comment: @a_maar browser sniffing is generally a bad idea and has been replaced by the likes of feature detection http://modernizr.com/